# WebSocket Connection failed with socketerror

Tags: c#, websocket, tls1.2, websocket4net, application-data

Client initiated the websocket connection TLS handshake is passed and Application data layer has started . I Can see first application data is sent from client to server and the respective Ack and then from server to client and respective Ack.
Then next [RST, ACK] is sent from client to server which results in Socket Error.

TLS Handshake process is completed

ClientHello

ServerHello,ServerCertificate, ServerKeyExchange , ServerHelloDone,

ClientKeyExchange, ChangeCipherSpec, EncryptedHandshakeMessage,[Client To Server]

ChangeCipherSpec, EncryptedHandshakeMessage [Server To Client]

ApplicationData [Client To Server]

ApplcationData [Server To Client]

[RST,ACK] - Failure

What could be the possible causes of this socket error?

Comment: Just to clarify: Client (ACK) <->Server (ACK) works fine, but Client (RST) -> Server (ACK) doesn't? Could you place the information about the error you're referring to?

Comment: @IliassNassibane  description modified

Comment: What's the literal error message?

Comment: just i get [SocketError], no specific reason.